# Theoretically, If you know the hash of a program one intends to install and you generate another file that hashes to that value what could you do?

Tags: hash

> If I know the hash of a program you intend to install is d306c9f6c5..., if I generate some other file that hashes to that value, I could wreak all sorts of havoc. - from https://nakamoto.com/hash-functions/

Theoretically, If you know the hash of a program one intends to install and you generate another file that hashes to that value what could you do?

Comment: So, how can you use collisions to your advantage?

Comment: Are you asking that you generate another program that has the same hash with the legal program than attacking them?

Comment: @schroeder I guess I'm asking how you can use collisions to your advantage in the context where you know the hash of a program one intends to install. I already get how you could use collisions if say you were able to login as someone else because you could enter something else that results in the same hash.

Answer (score 3):

Many application control products (aka, application whitelisting) use hashes to identify approved executables. If you duplicate the hash of an approved file, that would be sufficient to execute applications in most cases where such controls are used. Code signing also relies on file hashes.

The security of these products stems from two sources: first, it is very difficult to generate a preimage collision. (Your proposed attack is based on finding a preimage collision.)

Secure hashing algorithms are expected to be resistant to preimage collisions. This expectation can only be satisfied by mathematical evidence that stands up to examination by cryptography experts. There are a number of hashing algorithms that have no known, practical attacks. E.g., SHA256, SHA512, and SHA3.

Right now, the SHA1 algorithm is deprecated because a combination of new techniques and growth in compute capabilities have rendered it vulnerable to such collisions. The method requires thousands of dollars of compute (at bulk cloud compute rates), but it is feasible for well-funded organizations.

The other factor which makes preimage attacks difficult is that you may not know the hashing algorithm chosen by the target. It is essentially impossible to generate a collision for multiple algorithms. E.g., you cannot create a file that collides with the MD5, SHA1, and SHA256 hashes of another file simultaneously. So, you would need to know which algorithm to target.

In summary, there are serious implications if you can generate preimage collisions, but hashing algorithms are designed to make this virtually impossible for precisely that reason.

Comment: So you are saying that if you have a file that hashes to the same value as an approved executable than you can execute code?  I don't see how unless you happened to make an executable file with the same hash.  The quote from the question implies any file with the same hash.  The question asks how would you use a file with the same hash to "wreak all sorts of havoc"?

Comment: @BakonJarser 'Any file' includes executable files.

Comment: It is arguably easiest to wreak havoc with an executable, and the first sentence of the question implies he is looking at executables. But, yes, you are correct that there are more attack models than arbitrary code execution for preimage collisions.

Answer (score 0):

So there is a correct executable file with a hashcode matching a malicious file. Nothing bad happens until I can convince your computer to accept my malicious file. For example, if you try to download the correct executable and I manage to make you download the malicious file, you are in trouble.

If you use an enterprise backup system, that will often use checksums for files. So if *one* user installs the malicious app and is the first to back it up, your enterprise backup system would store the malicious file. If anyone else then tries to backup the *correct* executable, nothing is copied because of the matching checksum. If any user mangles up the executable and has to restore it from backup, he or she will get the malicious file.

So generating a file with same hashcode is not enough - you must actually make me use that file.